# Как сделать панель с метками в Яндекс.Картах?

Tags: javascript, html, яндекс-карты, iframe

Нужно добавить стилизованную карту на сайт. С такими же метками и боковой панелью:
http://www.umos-center.ru/#!net/cjg9

Есть два варианта:

1. Найти плагин, модуль, конструктор, где можно реализовать подобный функционал и главное, чтобы карту можно было кастомизовать.
2. Второй вариант — использовать этот фрейм и изменить стили в нём. Пытался так: `$('#frame').contents().find('.list-number').css('border', 'none');`. Но не получается выполнить `$('#frame').contents();`. Ругается.

Если у кого-то есть ещё варианты — прошу, подскажите. Я пока без понятия, что делать с этой проблемой. Завтра карта должна быть готова. :С

Стили уже отверстал. Вот как должно выглядеть: http://avafin.ru/umos/about.html

Comment: Ссылка из удаленного ответа: http://webmap-blog.ru/yandex-maps/sozdanie-karty-na-sajte-s-adresami-magazinov-s-ispolzovaniem-api-yandeks-kart-versii-2-x

Answer (score 1):

C API яндекса не сильно знаком, но точно помню, что при инициализации можно указывать центр карты. В вашем случае можно делать так

1. Загружаем список координат всех меток 
   ( api яндекс позволяет по адресу получить координаты, либо в ручную)
2. После этого показываем карту, с центром активной метки ( вешаем обработчик на событие `hover`, в нем перерисовываем карту ( либо двигаем ее, что бы центром стали нужные координаты )

[API Карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/quick-start/tasks/quick-start-docpage/)